# jquery to select option data and value when each dropdown has dynamically created id

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, razor

I need to auto populate the form based on the dropdown selection. I have multiple dropdown section with dynamic id. How can I use jquery to target dynamic id to get the both option value and data attribute to fill the input text area. I can get the value for predefined id but can't trigger jquery for unknown id.

```
@foreach(var number in totalNumber){

  <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8 ml-0 pr-1">
 
   <select  name="@number"  class="form-control mb-1">

       <option>Select from the dropdown</option>
         
        @foreach(var product in @Model.ProductList){
          
            <option value="@product.productName"
                    data-pd = "@product.productDescription"
                    data-model = "@product.productModelNo">
                    @product.productName</option>
        }
            
  </select>

  <input type="hidden" class="form-control mb-1" rows="1" placeholder="Product Name"/>

  <input type="hidden"  class="form-control mb-1" rows="1" placeholder="Product description"/>
    
  <input type="hidden" class="form-control mb-1" rows="1" placeholder="Product Model Number"/>
  
 </div>
}
```

I need to get product Name, product description and product model number on my input field based on the dropdown selection made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly add some class names to your hidden fields so that they can be easily identified by JQuery.

For example:

```
<input type="hidden" class="product-name form-control mb-1" rows="1" placeholder="Product Name" />
<input type="hidden" class="product-description form-control mb-1" rows="1" placeholder="Product description" />
<input type="hidden" class="product-model-no form-control mb-1" rows="1" placeholder="Product Model Number" />
```

Then to set hidden values on changing dropdown, use the `change()` method. You can find the hidden fields using `parent()` & `find()`.

**As an example:**

```
$('select').on('change', function () {
    var productName = this.value;
    var productDescription = $(this).find('option:selected').data("pd");
    var productModelNo = $(this).find('option:selected').data("model");
    $(this).parent().find(".product-name").val(productName);
    $(this).parent().find(".product-description").val(productDescription);
    $(this).parent().find(".product-model-no").val(productModelNo);
});
```

Heres a working example https://jsfiddle.net/54equvb0/2/

Comment: I am able to get the both selected value and data value but I am not able to set the value for my input using closest.

Comment: I've updated the answer. parent & find should do